# Is there a natural way to remove space between visual block in vim?

Tags: vim

Assume we have this code block:

```
function example(){
    href = "http:// google . com      ";
}
```

And also assume we visual selected the double quoted address.

How to remove space between visual block?

I searched the web but only found answers about 'removing trailing space'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can restrict a substitution to the last visual selection with `:help \%V`, one for each extremity of the visual selection:

```
:s/\%V\s\%V//g
```